# SELECT CASE to use NOT EXISTS in Oracle failing

Tags: oracle, plsql, rdbms

I have been trying to find a solution to use an If_Exists() style statement in Oracle PL SQL. I am trying to create a trigger which checks to see if a certain airsoft gun exists in the guns table when a member tries to input a new gun owned in the gunsOwned table. If the gun does not exist in the guns table, then it must be inputted to the table before the gun owned is inputted to the gunsOwned table or it will violate referential integrity as the Make and Model in gunsOwned are foreign keys to the Make and Model in the Guns table. However I keep getting Trigger created with compilation errors, and all of my attribute names are correct, so don't know why the select case statement is not working. Here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateGuns 
BEFORE INSERT ON GunsOwned  
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   MemberAddingGun NUMBER;
   NewMake VARCHAR2(30);
   NewModel VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
   MemberAddingGun := :NEW.OwnerID;
   NewMake := :NEW.MakeOwned;
   NewModel := :NEW.ModelOwned;
   SELECT CASE gunExists
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT Make, Model FROM Guns WHERE Make=NewMake AND Model=NewModel)
   THEN 
    INSERT INTO Guns VALUES(NewMake, NewModel);
   END
   UPDATE Member
   SET NumOfGuns = NumOfGuns+1
   WHERE MemberID = MemberAddingGun;
END updateGuns;
.
RUN;
```

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use simple INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE instead of `CASE` or `IF`  statements:

```
INSERT INTO Guns( colname1, colname2 )
SELECT NewMake, NewModel FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT null FROM Guns WHERE Make=NewMake AND Model=NewModel
);
```

BTW - on multiuser environment checking for not-existence of a record will always fail, since not commited records are not visible to SQL, and you will get duplicate records in Guns table. 
In such a case you need some kind of synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `IF` after setting up an appropriate flag:

```
DECLARE
   v_flag number;
BEGIN    
   SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM Guns
                             WHERE Make = :New.MakeOwned AND Model = :New.Model AND rownum = 1;
                            )
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END)
   INTO v_flag
   FROM DUAL;

   IF v_flag = 0
   THEN 
      INSERT INTO Guns(Make, Model) VALUES (:New.Make, :New.Model);
   END IF;

   UPDATE Member
       SET NumOfGuns = NumOfGuns + 1
       WHERE MemberID = :New.OwnerId;
END; -- updateGuns
```

I see no advantage to copying the fields in `:NEW` to local variables.  In fact, it makes the code a bit harder to follow, because the reader has to check if the values are different from the values in the `:NEW` record.

That said, an alternative is to have a unique index on `Guns(Make, Model)`, attempt an insert and just ignore the error using exceptions.

Comment: This is still returning the warning that trigger created with compilation errors. See the Guns(Make, Model) attributes make up the primary key together as a composite key, so are basically a unique linguistic index together.

Comment: @AndrewY . . . The `END IF` might fix the compilation error.

Comment: Still getting compilation errors not sure why! Could it be that the v_flag has to be equal to 0, and not null if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @AndrewY . . . That is incorrect, but it would be a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options. First, you can handle this using a MERGE statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateGuns 
  BEFORE INSERT ON GunsOwned  
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO GUNS
    USING (SELECT MAKE, MODEL FROM GUNS) g
      ON (g.MAKE = :NEW.MAKEOWNED AND g.MODEL = :NEW.MODELOWNED)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (MAKE, MODEL)
      VALUES (:NEW.MAKEOWNED, :NEW.MODELOWNED);

 UPDATE Member
   SET NumOfGuns = NumOfGuns+1
   WHERE MemberID = :NEW.OWNERID;
END UPDATEGUNS;
```

In this case the MERGE acts as a conditional INSERT, only adding a new row to GUNS if the specified make and model don't already exist in the table.

Alternatively, assuming that MAKE and MODEL are either the primary key or are a unique key on GUNS you can just go ahead and do the INSERT, trap the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception thrown if a duplicate is found, and proceed merrily on your way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateGuns
  BEFORE INSERT ON GunsOwned  
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO GUNS
      (MAKE, MODEL)
    VALUES
      VALUES (:NEW.MAKEOWNED, :NEW.MODELOWNED);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      NULL;  -- ignore the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception
  END;

 UPDATE Member
   SET NumOfGuns = NumOfGuns+1
   WHERE MemberID = :NEW.OWNERID;
END UPDATEGUNS;
```

Personally, I don't like ignoring exceptions - I'd rather write code which doesn't raise exceptions - but it's your choice.

Best of luck.